# Comparing grouped values based on highest values

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table in the following format :-

```
QUOTEID EAC         RN
50      23642.3     2
50      23292.8     1
126     18101.1     1
193     924621.1    12
193     121967.8    11
193     127852.3    10
193     129995.1    9
199     16520.8     1
```

In Oracle, I'd like to know if it possible to return QUOTEIDs where the last 2 EACs (determined by RN) are more than 30 % different, grouped by QUOTEID. Any QUOTEID with a MAX RN of 1 can be ignored.

So, using the data above, the expected output would be :-

```
QUOTEID 
193
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One method uses `row_number()` and aggregation:

```
select quoteid
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by quoteid order by rn desc) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
where seqnum <= 2
group by quoteid
having min(eac) < max(eac) * 0.7;
```

The `min()` and `max()` might look a bit odd.  However, the `where` filters down to just the last two rows, so the `min()` and `max()` refer to each of the last two values.  (Which depends on which is bigger.)

Your condition is symmetric so it doesn't make a difference which is which.  If the condition were not symmetric, you could use conditional aggregation.  Something like this:

```
having max(case when seqnum = 1 then eac end) / max(case when seqnum = 2 then eac end) between 0.7 and 1.3
```

(Differing by 30% is actually ambiguous and this is one reasonable interpretation.)